# get n-th element from a tuple inside array pySpark

Tags: python, arrays, list, pyspark, tuples

I'm working with pySpark and I want to retrieve a value from a list of tuple from a column. The structure looks like this when I print it after using toPandas().

```
[[Row(a = '1' , b = '2' , c = '3'), Row(a= '4' , b = '5' , c = '6')]]
```

and I want to get `['3' , '6']` as my result which is the third element of each element inside the list.

Comment: you want to get column C ? `df.select("C")`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand exactly what you're asking. Let's try this answer :

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

a = [[Row(a = '1' , b = '2' , c = '3'), Row(a= '4' , b = '5' , c = '6')]]

result = [j[2] for i in a for j in i]

print(result)
>['3', '6']
```